# VS Code C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets Error: не найдены ссылочные сборки для .NETFramework,Version=v4.7

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net, visual-studio-code, assembly

Работаю в Unity 2018. Обычно проекты и скрипты нормально подгружались в VS Code, но что-то сбилось и вот ошибка:

```
        не найдены ссылочные сборки для .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1. Чтобы устранить эту проблему, установите пакет разработчика (пакет SDK или пакет нацеливания) для этой версии платформы или перенацельте приложение. Пакеты разработчика для платформы .NET Framework можно скачать на странице https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'e:\Ivan\Игры Ивана (созданные им)\Оплот Империй\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
e:\Ivan\Игры Ивана (созданные им)\Оплот Империй\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): Error: не найдены ссылочные сборки для .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1. Чтобы устранить эту проблему, установите пакет разработчика (пакет SDK или пакет нацеливания) для этой версии платформы или перенацельте приложение. Пакеты разработчика для платформы .NET Framework можно скачать на странице https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks.
```

Установил уже 4.7, и 4.7.1, но результата 0. Есть идеи?

Comment: VS Code **не** поддерживает .NET Framework, только .NET Core и выше.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, но как же мне быть с этой проблемой?

Comment: Не использовать "блокнот" для программирования, а использовать полноценную IDE (Visual Studio)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если бы комп тянул и интерфейс был поприятнее. Мне больше Code нравится. Но спасибо за советы и помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимание, решение было найдено путем перепрочтения полного лога.
Прошу всех, у кого такая же проблема, читать внимательно лог ошибок.
Что же такого в нем нашел?
Оказывается, что нужно было установить .NET Framework 4.7.1 Developer Pack. Я же установил иную версию.
Итог: будьте внимательны и умейте читать и переводить.
Всем спасибо за попытки помочь.